# Numbers with pound sign not adding together

Tags: jquery

I have these two fields being passed from my API

```
Var1 = £23.45
Var2 = £67.89
```

How do I add these together in my jQuery?

I've tried

```
+Var1 + +Var2
```

But all I get in return is `NaNNaN`.

Comment: Its not a duplicate? I'm asking how to add two numbers together not find out what NaN standsfor!

Comment: I closed it so that you won't be getting - votes. Up to you! `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, they are invalid. If you want them to be added, you need to do something like this:

```
Var1 = "£23.45";  // Put it inside quotes. And give a semicolon.
Var2 = "£67.89";  // Put it inside quotes. And give a semicolon.
```

And now:

```
Var3 = "£" + (parseFloat(Var1.substr(1)) + parseFloat(Var2.substr(1)));  // £91.34
```

Now `Var3` will have the sum plus the `£` sign: `£91.34`.

```js
Var1 = "£23.45";  // Put it inside quotes. And give a semicolon.
Var2 = "£67.89";  // Put it inside quotes. And give a semicolon.
Var3 = "£" + (parseFloat(Var1.substr(1)) + parseFloat(Var2.substr(1)));  // £91.34
document.write(Var3);
```

You can use `.toFixed(2);` for formatting the decimal places:

```js
Var1 = "£23.45";  // Put it inside quotes. And give a semicolon.
Var2 = "£67.85";  // Put it inside quotes. And give a semicolon.
Var3 = "£" + (parseFloat(Var1.substr(1)) + parseFloat(Var2.substr(1))).toFixed(2);;  // £91.34
document.write(Var3);
```

*ps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061784/what-does-nan-stand-for-in-javascript/*

Comment: @SamAdmit See the snippet man. Click on Run Code Snippet and see.

Comment: Very close to what i need however its missing the last number, I'm getting 118.7 it should be 118.70???

Comment: @SamAdmit Both are same right? Value wise. To display it in two decimals, you need to format it using `.toFixed(2);`